# Cannot create topic with deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-deployment-manager

I am having trouble creating a PubSub topic using the deployment manager.

My config.yaml file has the following contents...

```
resources:
-  name: sam-poc-pubsub-assessment-end-topic
#  type: pubsub.v1.topic
   type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics
   properties:
       topic: assessment_end
```

When I create the deployment using the deployment manager, it reports that the deployment was successful...

```
The fingerprint of the deployment is 9LReFMsyG2iyEa44Y0PR0A==
Waiting for create [operation-1546634405048-57ea7e24f6ec0-e671c8b2-e3829b2e]...
.......done.
Create operation operation-1546634405048-57ea7e24f6ec0-e671c8b2-e3829b2e completed successfully.
NAME                                 TYPE              STATE      ERRORS  INTENT
sam-poc-pubsub-assessment-end-topic  gcp-types/pubsub  COMPLETED  []
                                     -v1:projects.top
                                     ics
```

But when I check the console, there are no PubSub topics present in my project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have more than one GCP project? `gcloud config list project` will show you your current project.

Comment: I do have multiple projects, but that is not the issue.  The config.yaml that I showed above is simplified.  The real file contains other resources that show up in the console after creating the deployment.  It's just the pubsub topics that fail to show up.